# problem with swiper inside modal react js

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, action, gallery, swiper.js

In a modal window, I have two swipers.
one is the main swiper and the second is the thumbs swiper, Everything is working fine except when I click on a slider from the thumbs swiper it should change the main slider, the modal close instead.
how to solve this problem, please...

this is the swiper component file

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Thumbs } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'


const SwiperWithGallery = ({ imagesArr }) => {
  const swiperRef = useRef(null)
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(swiperRef.current)
  const params = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    // pagination: {
    //   clickable: true,
    // },
    loop: false,
    navigation: false,
  }

  SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Thumbs])
  return (
    <div>
      <Swiper
        id="main"
        {...params}
        ref={swiperRef}
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
      >
        {imagesArr.map((item) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={item.id} className="cursor-pointer">
            <img src={item.src} width="400" height="400" />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        id="thumbs"
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        slidesPerView={4}
        spaceBetween={1}
        //freeMode={true}
        //watchSlidesVisibility={true}
        //watchSlidesProgress={true}
      >
        {imagesArr.map((item) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={item.id} className="cursor-pointer">
            <img src={item.src} width="75" height="75" />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
```

and here is the modal file

```js
<Modal
            isOpen={modal}
            toggle={toggleModal}
            className="modal-dialog-centered modal-lg"
          >
            <ModalBody>
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <Button
                  onClick={toggleModal}
                  color="default"
                  style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}
                >
                  <span className="h4">&times;</span>
                </Button>
              </div>
              <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={6}>
                  <SwiperWithGallery imagesArr={products} />
                </Col>
                </Row>
                </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue and found a workaround to fix it:

In the modal parent component I passed the callback as `onSwiper` to the swiper wrapper class(`SwiperWithGallery` in your case) and put the swiper instance to the state. [Sample here](https://swiperjs.com/react#controller)

Then, when I toggle a modal state I just re-initialize the swiper class through `swiperInstance.update();` and this works for me.

In result you should get something like this:

Swiper component wrapper:

```
// onSwiper - added as component props
const SwiperWithGallery = ({ imagesArr, onSwiper }) => {
  ...
  const params = {
    ...,
  }
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <Swiper
        id="main"
        {...params}
        onSwiper={onSwiper}
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
      >
...
```

Modal component:

```
const SomeParentComponent = () => {
    ...
    const [swiperClass, setSwiperClass] = useState(null);

    const toggleModal = () => {  
      changeModalState(!modal);
      if (swiperClass) {
        swiperClass.update();
      }
    };

    return (
          <Modal
            isOpen={modal}
            toggle={toggleModal}
            className="modal-dialog-centered modal-lg"
          >
          ...
          // Here I pass onSwiper function to set swiper class in state.
          <SwiperWithGallery onSwiper={setSwiperClass} imagesArr={products} />
          ..
      </Modal>
  );
}
```